# Show custom text at "My personal information" page through plugin

Tags: prestashop

I want to show some custom text at "My personal information" page in customer's account using a plugin in Prestashop. I have no idea how to do this?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it by a plugin or module, because prestashop is not providing any HOOK for that page / place. 
But you can do it by a little work out there. I am considering you are using prestashop 1.5 , so lets work with that.

1) First create a cms page at admin and note its id. Lets consider its id is 10.
2) Now open the file **override/controllers/front/IdentityController.php** . In this class file create a function like below.

```
public function initContent()
{
    parent::initContent();
    $identityCmsPage = new CMS(10, $this->context->language->id_lang);
    $this->context->smarty->assign('identityCmsPage', $identityCmsPage);

}
```

Now after that, open file at your themes folder **themes/your theme/indentity.tpl**

and display that cms page contents like

```
{$identityCmsPage->content}
```

and you will have that cms page contents there.

**Note: This code is not tested and may have errors. Please adjust accordingly if you got any.**